# Interpretation of (opt) in C++standard

Tags: c++, syntax, language-lawyer, grammar

How to interpret *(opt)*? Is it applied to the whole "compound" word or just to the word to which it is attached?

In the example below it is obvious that it is applied to the whole "compound" word. But if it is so in all cases? Where can I find the rule for it?

`statement:
   labeled-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) expression-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) compound-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) selection-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) iteration-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) jump-statement
   declaration-statement
   attribute-specifier-seq(opt) try-block`

Comment: "***opt**ional*"?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/syntax

Comment: Attribute specifiers are *optional*.  Not so common on statements, but, say, [[fallthrough]] on case-statements or [[likely]] on if-statements.

Comment: @HansPassant Is *opt* applied only to the word *seq* or to the whole compound word *attribute-specifier-seq*?

Comment: It is one word.

Comment: *attribute-specifier-seq* is the name of a particular element of the grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It applies to the whole word.  For example,

> *foo-bar*<sub>*opt*</sub> *baz*

is equivalent to

> *baz*
>   *foo-bar* *baz*

and not

> *foo* *baz*
>   *foo-bar* *baz*

per [[syntax]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/syntax#1):

> In the syntax notation used in this document, syntactic categories are
>   indicated by *italic* type, and literal words and characters in
>   `constant width` type. Alternatives are listed on separate lines
>   except in a few cases where a long set of alternatives is marked by
>   the phrase “one of”. If the text of an alternative is too long to fit
>   on a line, the text is continued on subsequent lines indented from the
>   first one. **An optional terminal or non-terminal symbol** is indicated by
>   the subscript “<sub>*opt*</sub>”, so
>
> > `{` *expression*<sub>*opt*</sub> `}`
>
> indicates an optional expression enclosed in braces.

The whole compound word is a non-terminal.  Things like *seq* aren't terminals or non-terminals.

Comment: @L.F.I made a small correction (bar baz-->foo baz) after "and not". Please, check if it is correct.